# Process dialog problem..!

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am doing an app in which i have an activity with two buttons(ex: Submit and cancel) when user tapping on submit button i am displaying the process dialog and doing some background task or service calling stuff but the problem is when user taps on home hard hey while process dialog is showing the app will be deactivated or paused, And when user is back to the app i.e when the app is re-activated or resumed then i am unable to click the submit and cancel buttons again i have to press the  back hard key to get the focus on the app, According my observation i came to one conclusion that process dialog is the blocker of my app. How to solve this issue?? How to suspend the process dialog when the app is paused or deactivated??

Thanks,
Ram.

Answer (score 0):

it will be better if you can put up code Like `cancelDialog(id)` in your **onPause** and `showDialog(id)` in **onResume** with conditions of course.

I hope you are creating Dialogs i `nonCreateDialog(int id)`